# 401 Unauthorized error when trying to send Gmail from a different email address

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, alias, http-status-code-401

I am trying to generate Google Doc using script and then send it to email.
Everything works fine when I'm giving my email as "from" parameter(I generate this doc with my Google account).

```
GmailApp.sendEmail


(
   invoice.customerEmail, 
   'title', 
   invoice.emailBody, 
   {
     attachments: [doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'subject title',
     htmlBody: invoice.emailBody, 
     from: 'myemail@gmail.com'
   }
 );
```

Problem arises when I type in other email in 'from'. I published it as web app. Here are the settings :
[image: settingsgoogle]

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Whose email are you trying to impersonate?

Comment: @TheMaster It's also my email but different account

Comment: 1.Is the email registered alias for your account ? 2. What is the problem that arises? Quote the exact text of error and the line that produces it.

Comment: Other email I am trying to use(this is when error happens) is not registered as an alias. That is probably the reason. I'll register it and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to the `GmailApp` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)):**

> `from` >  the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by `getAliases()`

Therefore, you can use the `sendEmail` with other email addresses **only** if these email addresses are aliases of the email executing the script.

However, if you don't want to add this other email as your alias, you can simply create the script on this other account and execute it from there.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script GmailApp Class - sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options);
- [GmailApp sendEmail() Advanced parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#advanced-parameters_1).